# making animated nav bar with hover effect for the web page

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover, transition

I want to make a animated navigation bar using hover effect for my web page and I saw multiple tutorials  on how to make one , yet I am unable to get a nice smooth transition.So I wanted to know where is it wrong and what is the best way to make a animated navigation bar with hover effect.

Thank you

Here is my code and I am only using HTML and CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible">
      <meta name="viewport">
    <title>form website practice</title>
<style>
h1{
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
}

.submit{
font-size:2rem;
font-weight:700;
padding:0.5em 1em;
color:red;
input[type=button] {
  accent-color: red;
}
background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
border:10px solid var(accent-color:red);
border-radius:10px;
transition:transform 0.3s;background-color 0.3s,color 0.3s;
}

.submit:hover{
transform:translateY(-10px);
background-color:var(--clr-accent);
color:var(--clr-light);
}
body{
text-align:center;
color:white;
background:black;
}
 nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 420px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    box-shadow: 0 25px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

}
li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display:block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin:10px;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:500;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;

}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  transition: color 0.5s;
}
li::after{
content:'';
width:100%;
height:100%;
border-radius:30px;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
left:50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
z-index:-1;
opacity:0;
}
li a:hover::after {
  top:50%;
  opacity:1;
  transition: top 0.5s , opacity 0.5s;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>WELCOME TO MY FORM WEBSITE</h1>
<nav>
<li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Legal">Legal</a></li>
</nav>
<form>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="First Name"><br>
    <br><br>
    <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
      <input type="text" id="lastname" name="Lastname"><br>
    <br><br>
    <label for="DOB">DOB</label>
      <input type="date" id="DOB" name="DOB"><br>
    <br><br>
    <label for="email">E-mail ID</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="emailinput" placeholder="Please enter email"
            pattern=".+@gmail.com"> <span id="message"></span>
    <br><br>
    <label for="destination">Select Destination</label>
     <select name="destination" id="destination">
         <option value=" "> </option>
    <option value="chota">Chhota-Imambara</option>
    <option value="ajmer">Ajmer</option>
    <option value="mawsynram">Mawsynram</option>
    <option value="amritsar">Amritsar</option>
         <option value="hampi">Hampi</option>
          <option value="rishikesh">Rishikesh</option>
          <option value="jaisalmer">Jaisalmer</option>
          <option value="lonavala">Lonavala</option>
          <option value="shimla">Shimla</option>
          <option value="hampi">Hampi</option>
  </select>
    <br><br>
    <button class="submit">submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap navbar instead of creating your own nav bar